# Spring Boot + Jetty + TLS1.2 (HTTPS)

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, https

Buenos días a todos,

Tengo una aplicación funcionando en local con Spring Boot y Jetty. El problema viene cuando intento añadir TLS1.2 a mi proyecto para que soporte el HTTPS. Me funciona a la perfección con http pero ahora quiero que los servicios se publiquen en https con TLS1.2. Y aquí es cuando me falla y obtengo errores.

Obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedJetty.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties': Could not bind properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'ssl[keyAlias]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'ssl[keyAlias]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'ssl[keyAlias]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties]: Bean property 'ssl[keyAlias]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:135)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:130)
at com.viajesurbis.Application.main(Application.java:21)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
```

Este es mi pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>springboot-jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>springboot-jersey</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <jersey.version>2.8</jersey.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Este es mi main donde arranco mi aplicación:

```
        package com.viajesurbis;

import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.viajesurbis.config.JerseyConfig;
import com.viajesurbis.rest.RestResource;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { RestResource.class })
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).showBanner(false).run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(), "/rest/*");
        registration.addInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, JerseyConfig.class.getName());
        return registration;
    }

}
```

Este es mi fichero application.properties: (Este fichero se encuentra en la ruta src/main/resources de mi proyecto)

```
server.port: 8443
server.ssl.key-store: keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: #REMOVED#
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: jetty
```

También tengo el archivo llamado keystore.p12 en la ruta src/main/resources y por si acaso también he metido el keystrore.p12 en el proyecto, donde se encuentra el pom.xml. Es decir, tengo el archivo duplicado pero me sigue sin funcionar.

Si elimino el contenido del application.properties entonces la aplicación me funciona perfectamente pero en HTTP y yo quiero que funcione en HTTPS.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.
Un saludo,

Comment: Por favor, ¿algún usuario me puede ayudar?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que instalar ese certificado en tu keystore local, cuando haces eso uno de los parametros es el alias

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias server -file your_site_name.p7b -keystore your_site_name.jks
```

Ese alias es el que esta buscando tu configuracion.